# What is the correct SQL statement to return the data I want?

Tags: sql

I have the logic that will get me the data I want but I need it to be in one query. I am ultimately looking for unit_serial_number

```
SELECT TOP 1 trans_seq 
FROM "micros"."dtl" 
where ob_dtl05_void_flag = 'T' 
order by date_time DESC
```

gets me the trans_seq

```
SELECT chk_seq 
from "micros"."trans_dtl" 
where trans_seq = '9915'
```

gets me the chk_seq using the trans_seq from 1st query

```
SELECT unit_serial_number 
from "acibingo"."aci_bingo_sell_unit" 
where chk_seq = '9590'
```

gets me the unit_serial_number from the chk_seq returned in the second query

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if you simply put the queries in parenthesis isntead of the results, then this would put in all one query I believe:

```
SELECT unit_serial_number 
FROM "acibingo"."aci_bingo_sell_unit" 
where chk_seq = 
    (SELECT chk_seq 
     FROM "micros"."trans_dtl" 
     WHERE trans_seq =
         (SELECT TOP 1 trans_seq 
          FROM "micros"."dtl" 
          WHERE ob_dtl05_void_flag = 'T' order by date_time DESC
         )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the queries in the `where` clause (if they return only 1 row as you mention in your question):

```
SELECT unit_serial_number 
from "acibingo"."aci_bingo_sell_unit" 
where chk_seq = (
  SELECT chk_seq 
  from "micros"."trans_dtl" 
  where trans_seq = (
    SELECT TOP 1 trans_seq 
    FROM "micros"."dtl" 
    where ob_dtl05_void_flag = 'T' 
    order by date_time DESC
  )
)
```

Alternatively you can use 2 `CTE`s:

```
with 
  cte1 (
    SELECT TOP 1 trans_seq 
    FROM "micros"."dtl" 
    where ob_dtl05_void_flag = 'T' 
    order by date_time DESC
  ),
  cte2 (
    SELECT chk_seq 
    from "micros"."trans_dtl" 
    where trans_seq = (select trans_seq from cte1)
  )
SELECT unit_serial_number 
from "acibingo"."aci_bingo_sell_unit" 
where chk_seq = (select chk_seq from cte2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join the last two tables and use a subquery to compute the value for the first one, as in:

```
select u.unit_serial_number 
from "acibingo"."aci_bingo_sell_unit" u
join "micros"."trans_dtl" d on d.chk_seq = u.chk_seq
where d.trans_seq = (
  select top 1 trans_seq 
  from "micros"."dtl" 
  where ob_dtl05_void_flag = 'T' 
  order by date_time desc
)
```